# Mumford's computation of the determinant of cohomology of a relative curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

In [Integral Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703305.pdf), Pappas mentions that Mumford computed the determinant of cohomology of $f:X\to S$ a relative curve integrally, and thus proved an integral version of GRR in that setting over a base of arbitrary characteristic.

Does anyone know where this is written down? I asked Pappas himself, but he'd misplaced the reference. I'm also interested in whether there are other known calculations of the determinant of cohomology; I'd guess, based on this result of Mumford, that maybe for $f$ a (principally polarized?) abelian scheme, something similar is possibly in that setting. Without knowing what Mumford's original argument is, however, I'm at a loss.

Comment: It is at the end of Mumford’s article in “L’Ensignement Mathematique.”